# Image upload with resize

Tags: php, image, upload, resize

i have a upload script and that works fine, but i want that its upload twice, one orginal format and one in a thubm size.

I did allready search on google and stackoverflow and i tried allready something, but i dont get it work.

My upload script

```
    // If you want to ignore the uploaded files, 
    // set $demo_mode to true;

$demo_mode = false;
$upload_dir = 'uploads/';
$allowed_ext = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');

include('./../includes/core.php');

if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'post'){
    exit_status('Error! Wrong HTTP method!');
}


if(array_key_exists('pic',$_FILES) && $_FILES['pic']['error'] == 0 ){

    $pic = $_FILES['pic'];

    if(!in_array(get_extension($pic['name']),$allowed_ext)){
        exit_status('Alleen '.implode(',',$allowed_ext).' bestanden zijn toegestaan');
    }   

    if($demo_mode){

        // File uploads are ignored. We only log them.

        $line = implode('       ', array( date('r'), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $pic['size'], $pic['name']));
        file_put_contents('log.txt', $line.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

        exit_status('Uploads are ignored in demo mode.');
    }


    // Move the uploaded file from the temporary 
    // directory to the uploads folder:

    $name = $pic['name'];
    $sname = hashing($name);
    $datum = date("d-m-Y"); 
    if(move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$sname)){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO foto VALUES ('','".$pic['name']."','".$sname."', '".$datum."', '0')");
        exit_status('Bestand succesvol geupload');
    }

}

exit_status('Er is iets mis gegaan!');


// Helper functions

function exit_status($str){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>$str));
    exit;
}
function hashing($naam){
    $info = pathinfo($naam);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $hash = basename($naam, $ext);
    $hash = $hash . genRandomstring();
    $hash = md5($hash);
    $hash = $hash . '-' . genRandomstring();
    return  $hash . $ext;
}
function genRandomString() {
$length = 5;
$string = "";
$characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-+!@"; // change to whatever characters you want
while ($length > 0) {
    $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0,strlen($characters)-1)];
    $length -= 1;
}
return $string;
}



function get_extension($file_name){
    $ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $ext = array_pop($ext);
    return strtolower($ext);
}
?>
```

If someone can help me? I will be very happy then becuase i have allready try this for a week and i can get it out.

Thanks, Chris

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: copy the code relating to pic (in the form and php) and add it again replacing 'pic' with 'thumb'

Answer (score 0):

1. You have the image uploaded *once*, which is all you need, then use that to create the second thumbnail file.
2. Try looking over the [GD documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned before you don't need to upload twice, copy and resize image once it's uploaded like this:

```
    $pathToImages = "path/to/images"
    $pathToThumbs = "path/to/thumbs"
    $fname = "image-file-name";
    $new_fname = "thumb-file-name";
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( "{$pathToImages}{$fname}" );
    $width = imagesx( $img );
    $height = imagesy( $img );
    $thumbWidth = //someValue//;
    $thumbHeight = //someValue//;

// calculate thumbnail size
    $new_height = floor($height * ($thumbWidth/$width));
    $new_width = $thumbWidth;

    // create a new temporary image
    $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);


    // copy and resize old image into new image 
    imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width,$new_height, $width, $height );

    // save thumbnail into a file
    imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$new_fname}" );
```

Comment: did you type the path to images and thumbs correctly? there should be no slash at the beginning of the path, for example "/upload/" is wrong "upload/" is correct

Comment: yeah i did, have you skype ?